# When press the button, it will be brought to front of another button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Hi I have to buttons like the following:

## XML

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/total_price_detailed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/total_amount_price"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

        <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonIranSansFont
            android:id="@+id/total_amount_proforma_invoice"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="جزئیات خرید"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/white_in_dark_background"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
            android:id="@+id/total_price_counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/total_amount_proforma_invoice"
            android:layout_margin="9dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_white_button"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:minWidth="30dp"
            android:paddingEnd="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black_overlay"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

when I hold click to `total_amount_proforma_invoice` in a ripple mode, it will be brought to in front of another button and when I release it, it will be OK, I don't want to have this and I always want to have `total_amount_proforma_invoice`back to `total_price_counter`.
What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this:**

**Update:**

Only add: `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` in `@+id/total_amount_proforma_invoice` View.

**Example:**

```
<com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonIranSansFont
            android:id="@+id/total_amount_proforma_invoice"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="جزئیات خرید"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/white_in_dark_background"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Works Fine.

Comment: Only add: `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` in `@+id/total_amount_proforma_invoice` View.